# How do I open this Python package?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I want to open this in a tool that can open it as a project and show me the project hierarchy. Can this be done in MS Visual Studio? If so, how?

I want to figure out how this package works. I can open individual files in Notepad++ but that is not good enough.

Comment: what kind of project hierachy do you expect? The following website describes how Python packages should be structured: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/
I personally prefer VSC or derivates for working and analysing python code.

Comment: OK, when I goto Visual Studio it expects a VS Solution file to exist there which does not exist there. This is what has confused me.

Comment: In general python code is not organized in project form like C/C++, so in general Visual Studio dont need these solution files. I am honest that I don't really like Visual Studio in general because of this solution and project structure, which I would describe as counter-intuitive. What I was mention is Visual Studio Code, which is totally different to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can just open this as a folder in Visual Studio and click on the subdirectories to unfold them. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Why does Visual Studio expect a solution or VS project file there? None of them exist there. So how do I open this in Visual Studio such that it understands what this is i.e a Python package?

Answer (score 0):

Just clone it. This is pretty easy solution.

[image]

output

[image]

Comment: Why does Visual Studio expect a solution or VS project file there? None of them exist there. So how do I open this in Visual Studio such that it understands what this is i.e a Python package?

Comment: it is a python package so you should install 
python support
TOOLS > Get Tools and Features... then tick Python development checkbox.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-support-in-visual-studio

After installing python support, you can open your existing package as python project
here are screenshots :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/quickstart-01-python-in-visual-studio-project-from-existing-code?view=vs-2019

Missing .sln file is generated, this should solve the problem